# \hspace at beginning of paragraph

Tags: spacing

In many cases it makes sense that `\hspace` is ignored at the beginning of a new line (and this has been discussed many times).  Yet why is `\hspace` not ignored at the beginning of a paragraph?  Is this intentional?  What is the rationale for this?  If `\hspace` is part of a macro, I'd prefer that `\hspace` is ignored no matter whether it appears at the beginning of a newline inside a paragraph or at the beginning of a paragraph.  How can one achieve that?

Here is a simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

foo bar\\ baz

\hspace{2em} hspace indents at beginning of paragraph.\\
\hspace{2em} Otherwise it does not indent at beginning of line

Why?

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\hspace` expands to, essentially `\hskip` which produces what TeX calls "glue." Glue belong to the class of *discardable* items. These are the things TeX throws away at a line break. Since `\\` is essentially `\unskip\nobreak\hfil\break`, TeX throws away the following `\hskip`.

To prevent discarding the glue, you can use `\hspace*`. But this isn't what you wanted.

You wanted a way to ignore the space at the beginning of the line as well. One possible way to do that is to make a new spacing macro that only inserts the space in horizontal mode.

```
\newcommand*\smarthspace[1]{%
    \ifhmode
        \hspace{#1}%
    \fi
}
```

The two caveats here are that normal paragraph indentation will still happen and using `\noindent` to suppress it will cause TeX to switch to horizontal mode and thus the space will be inserted. I don't have a good solution for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\smarthspace[1]{%
    \ifhmode
        \hspace{#1}%
    \fi
}
\begin{document}

foo bar\\ baz

\smarthspace{2em} smarthspace does not add a space at beginning of paragraph\\
\smarthspace{2em} nor at the beginning of a line.\smarthspace{2em} It will in
the middle.

\end{document}
```

[image]